# Pause in middle of javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I am trying to pause in the middle of a function for a given period of time (5 secs)

this is what I tried, but It doesn't work

```
(function MessagesAjax() {
    $.post('/api/messages/get', function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $.jGrowl(data[i].Body.toString().substring(0, 150), { header: 'New Message', sticky: true, });
            markDisplayed(data[i].Id);
        }
        setTimeout(MessagesAjax, 5000);
    });
})();

function markDisplayed(id) {
    setTimeout(5000);             //want it to pause here
    $.post("/api/messages/markdisplayed" + id);
    console.log("Marking displayed");
}
```

I just need it to pause so there is a delay before the post is sent back to the server

I'm almost sure that setTimeout is not what I want, but I'm not sure what else to use

Comment: [`setTimeout(callback,delay)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) will wait the given time `delay`and then execute `callback`. It won't delay the current script, instead it will add `callback` to a queue for the event loop (or something similar).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change markDisplayed to:

```
function markDisplayed(id) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.post("/api/messages/markdisplayed" + id);
        console.log("Marking displayed");
    }, 5000);
}​
```

This will cause the function to wait for five seconds before executing the content within it.

Comment: You should probably move `setTimeout(MessagesAjax, 5000);` from the MessageAjax function into the markDisplayed timeout as well. Otherwise I believe you will build up a queue of request pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

replacing

```
function markDisplayed(id) {
    setTimeout(5000);             //want it to pause here
    $.post("/api/messages/markdisplayed" + id);
    console.log("Marking displayed");
}
```

with

```
function markDisplayed(id) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      $.post("/api/messages/markdisplayed" + id);
      console.log("Marking displayed");
      },5000);             //want it to pause here
}
```

may work for you.